# Error Trigger en Postgresql syntax Error cerca en Create

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgresql-12

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER actualizar_almacen 
AFTER UPDATE OF unid_vendidas ON producto
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE almacen
    SET almacen.stock = almacen.stock
        + :OLD.unid_vendidas - :NEW.unid_vendidas
WHERE almacen.cod_prod_s =:NEW.cod_prod;
END actualizar_almacen;
```

estoy intentando crear un trigger en postgresql para que me mantenga actualizado el stock del ALMACEN cada vez que se vendan unidades de un determinado producto. Pero al ejecutar la sentencia el resultado arroja: ERROR: syntax error at or near "Create" LINE 4: ¿Qué tengo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que ese código no es de PostgreSQL. En PostgreSQL los trigger se dividen en dos:

- La función trigger(tiene tu código a ejecutar)
- El trigger (que llama a la función trigger)

por ejemplo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function fn_trigger () returns trigger as
$$
BEGIN
 UPDATE almacen
    SET almacen.stock = almacen.stock
        + OLD.unid_vendidas - NEW.unid_vendidas
WHERE almacen.cod_prod_s =NEW.cod_prod;

RETURN NEW;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER actualizar_almacen 
AFTER UPDATE OF categoryname ON categories
FOR EACH ROW execute procedure fn_trigger();
```

Comment: Si, me di cuenta.
Lo que tenia allí era algo de Oracle, el profesor lo habia dado como ejemplo pero no recordaba que tenia que pasarlo a PSQL.
Ese ejemplo que diste seria la conversión? Gracias de ante mano amigo

Comment: Si, le hice unos ajustes para PostgreSQL